# How to check the upload status while uploading files using Multer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

While uploading files using **Multa** does **`res.files`** or **`res.file`** include the file|files that the user sent for upload or the files that were uploaded successfully?

If these are not the files that were successfully uploaded, how can check each of the files for whether it was a successful upload, partial or there was an error or failure?

Thank you all in advance.